# Replacing the resistor with a source such that circuit remains unchanged

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors, resistance, current-source, voltage-source

[image]

The circuit here should remain unaffected , the Voltage across 2ohm resistor is given 20 V. If we replace the **A-B 5 ohm** resistor with which of the following a) 25V voltage source or b) 2 A current source and what polarity.

So, as Voltage across 2 Ohm resistor is 20V anyways it means current across it is 10 Amps left to right. Now that current flows through parallel resistors and divide among those 5 Ohm resistors, with 5 amperes in each.
So, if i choose (+) upward 25 V source to replace the voltage across other 5 Ohm resistor increases i=V/R giving it 5 amps of extra current does the circuit remain unchanged? . How do i check for 2A current source then?

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. I've read it a few times now and I'm confused about what you are asking.

Comment: The 5 ohm resistor is to be replaced with either a Voltage source of 25 V, or a current source of 2A so simply which of them is appropriate for this circuit. (Given Voltage across 2 ohm resistor is 20 V and though the question doesn't mention it ideal sources have to be assumed)

Comment: What value is \$E\$?

Comment: Nope, its value is not mentioned and its not required either, just have to eliminate the 5ohm resistance across A-B and replace it with either of the mentioned sources.

Comment: OK I see that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit can't remain unchanged since you're removing a resistor and adding a source. That's an obvious change.

However, the node voltages and branch currents will remain unchanged if you replace the 5 ohm resistor with a 25 V source (positive side on node "A").  There's no "extra" current since the voltage at node "A" is not changing.

Comment: @Adyy Edited to include polarity.